# Is there a way to get VMs Operating System name from Hyper-V using powershell?

Tags: powershell, automation, virtual-machine, wmi, hyper-v

I'm writing a script on HYPER-V host for getting VMs guest informations. Is there a way to get VMs Operating System name from Hyper-V using powershell?

There are several examples using `(Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName $vmName).name` but i should get this information directly from Hyper-V because of domain restrictions.

Also i'm using hyper-v module of powershell but i couldn't see any cmdlets related to OS.

Comment: Have you looked at [Msvm_VirtualSystemManagementService class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh850062(v=vs.85).aspx) already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be retrieved from guest intrinsic exchange items.

```
# Filter for parsing XML data
filter Import-CimXml 
{ 
   # Create new XML object from input
   $CimXml = [Xml]$_ 
   $CimObj = New-Object -TypeName System.Object 

   # Iterate over the data and pull out just the value name and data for each entry
   foreach ($CimProperty in $CimXml.SelectNodes("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Name']")) 
      { 
         $CimObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $CimProperty.NAME -Value $CimProperty.VALUE 
      } 

   foreach ($CimProperty in $CimXml.SelectNodes("/INSTANCE/PROPERTY[@NAME='Data']")) 
      { 
         $CimObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $CimProperty.NAME -Value $CimProperty.VALUE 
      } 

   # Display output
   $CimObj 
} 

# Prompt for the Hyper-V Server to use
$HyperVServer = Read-Host "Specify the Hyper-V Server to use (enter '.' for the local computer)"

# Prompt for the virtual machine to use
$VMName = Read-Host "Specify the name of the virtual machine"

# Get the virtual machine object
$query = "Select * From Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName='" + $VMName + "'"
$Vm = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query $query -computername $HyperVServer

# Get the KVP Object
$query = "Associators of {$Vm} Where AssocClass=Msvm_SystemDevice ResultClass=Msvm_KvpExchangeComponent"
$Kvp = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query $query -computername $HyperVServer

Write-Host
Write-Host "Guest KVP information for" $VMName

# Filter the results
try {
    $Kvp.GuestIntrinsicExchangeItems | Import-CimXml | where Name -eq "OSName"
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Not found"
}
```

From [Ben Armstrong’s Virtualization Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/virtual_pc_guy/2008/11/18/hyper-v-script-looking-at-kvp-guestintrinsicexchangeitems/).

Comment: This is really good answer. But It won't work if VM is down, as matter of fact none of the solutions will work if machine is down. +1

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're using SCVMM, Guest OS details are not available via Hyper-V PowerShell cmdlets.

You have to query the Guest itself like you've already found.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't run *t1meless*' script on PowerShell version 7.1, because `gwmi` is deprecated in 7.1, sources [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-wmiobject?view=powershell-5.1&viewFallbackFrom=powershell-7.1) and [GitHub](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/4766).
I rewrote the script for PS 7.1.

```ps
# Script for retrieving Hyper-V Guest Operating System.
# Tested on PowerShell 7.1

# Prompt for the Hyper-V Server to use
$hyper_v_server = Read-Host "Specify the Hyper-V Server to use (enter '.' for the local computer)"

# Prompt for the virtual machine to use
$vm_name = Read-Host "Specify the name of the virtual machine"

# Check if VM exists and is running. This script doesn't work if the VM is stopped.
# Capture error output, source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66861283/3498768
$vm_not_found = $($vm_state = (Get-VM $vm_name).state) 2>&1

if ($vm_not_found -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "$vm_name VM was not found."
    exit
}

if ($vm_state -eq "Off") {
    Write-Host "Cannot retrieve information of $vm_name. The VM is stopped. Only running VM information can be retrieved."
    exit
}

# Get the virtual machine object
$query = "Select * From Msvm_ComputerSystem Where ElementName='" + $vm_name + "'"
$vm = Get-CimInstance -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query $query -computername $hyper_v_server

# Get associated information
$vm_info = Get-CimAssociatedInstance -InputObject $vm

Write-Host "Guest information for" $vm_name

# Select only required information
$vm_info | Where GuestOperatingSystem |
    Select -Property GuestOperatingSystem |
    Format-List *
```