# How to get Hyper-V VM Guest OS

Tags: c#, wmi, hyper-v

I am trying to get Hyper-V Virtual machine guest OS details. But could not find any way to do that. Is there any way to get guest OS details from Hyper-V virtual machine using WMI C#?

Comment: Use PowerShell: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/?view=win10-ps

Comment: There is no way to get it with Hyper-V PowerShell. This post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38096777/is-there-a-way-to-get-vms-operating-system-name-from-hyper-v-using-powershell

Answer (score 0):

I found it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hyperv_v2/getsummaryinformation-msvm-virtualsystemmanagementservice#examples

We just need to add GuestOperatingSystem (106) in the requestedInformation.

Comment: Does it get RAM, CPU, Disk data?