# Redirecting stdout and stderr to file and console

Tags: powershell, io-redirection

In a powershell script, I call a program and want to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to *different* files, while still showing the output of both in the console. So basically, I want

```
stdout -> stdout
stdout -> out.log
stderr -> stderr
stderr -> err.log
```

So far, I came up with this code, but unfortunately it only fulfils requirements 1, 2 and 4. Stderr is not printed on the screen.

```
& program 2>"err.log" | Tee-Object -FilePath "out.log" -Append | Write-Host
```

How can I print `stderr` to the console also? Since writing to `stderr` produces red typeface, I don't want to redirect `stderr` to `stdout`, since then I would lose the visual impression of the error.

Comment: Isn't this a duplicate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24222088/powershell-capture-program-stdout-and-stderr-to-separate-variables ? Do you want to post the output _immediately_ to the console?

Comment: @Clijsters When `program` runs a long time, it could be good to have some intermediate output. But nontheless, this is a good workaround.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Taking a cue from [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jenss/2013/02/14/powershell-stdout-go-out-stderr-go-everywhere/) you could write a custom `tee` function that distinguishes input by object type and writes to the corresponding output file. Something like this:

```
function Tee-Custom {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory=$true,
            ValueFromPipeline=$true,
            ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true
        )]
        [array]$InputObject,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$OutputLogfile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [string]$ErrorLogfile,

        [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
        [switch]$Append
    )

    Begin {
        if (-not $Append.IsPresent) {
            if ($OutputLogfile -and (Test-Path -LiteralPath $OutputLogfile)) {
                Clear-Content -LiteralPath $OutputLogfile -Force
            }
            if ($ErrorLogfile -and (Test-Path -LiteralPath $ErrorLogfile)) {
                Clear-Content -LiteralPath $ErrorLogfile -Force
            }
        }
    }
    Process {
        $InputObject | ForEach-Object {
            $params = @{'InputObject' = $_}
            if ($_ -is [Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
                if ($ErrorLogfile) { $params['FilePath'] = $ErrorLogfile }
            } else {
                if ($OutputLogfile) { $params['FilePath'] = $OutputLogfile }
            }
            Tee-Object @params -Append
        }
    }
}
```

which could be used like this:

```
& program.exe 2>&1 | Tee-Custom -OutputLogfile 'out.log' -ErrorLogfile 'err.log' -Append
```