# PowerShell stderr redirect to file inserts newlines

Tags: powershell, stderr, io-redirection

Edit: I created a PowerShell UserVoice ["suggestion"](https://windowsserver.uservoice.com/forums/301869-powershell/suggestions/33255049-bug-powershell-stderr-redirect-to-file-inserts-ne) for (against?) this behavior; feel free to upvote.

PowerShell (5.1.16299.98, Windows 10 Pro 10.0.16299) is inserting newlines into my stderr when I redirect to file—as if to format for the console. Let's generate error messages of arbitrary length:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Console.Error.WriteLine(new string('x', int.Parse(args[0])));
    }
}
```

I compiled the above to `longerr.exe`. Then I call it like this:

```
$ .\longerr.exe 60 2>error.txt
```

I ran the following script in a PowerShell console with window width 60:

```
$h = '.\longerr.exe : '.Length
$w = 60 - 1
$f = 'error.txt'
Remove-Item $f -ea Ignore
(($w-$h), ($w-$h+1), ($w), ($w+1), ($w*2-$h), ($w*2-$h+1)) |
    % { 
        $_ >> $f
        .\longerr.exe $_ 2>>$f
    }
```

Now in a wider console I ran the following:

```
$ Get-Content $f | Select-String '^(?![+\t]|At line|  )'
```

(I could have just opened the file in a text editor and trimmed lines.) Here's the output:

```
43
.\longerr.exe : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

44
.\longerr.exe : 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

59
.\longerr.exe : 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

60
.\longerr.exe : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

102
.\longerr.exe : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

103
.\longerr.exe : xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
x
```

Why is PowerShell doing this? Can I make it stop? I'd rather not have to do something like this:

```
        .\longerr.exe $_ 2>&1 |
            % {
                if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
                    $_.Exception.Message | Out-File -FilePath $f -Append
                }
            }
```

First, all the opening and closing of that file can be slow (I know I can add *more code* and use a `StreamWriter`), and second, there is still a problem (bug?) with that approach, which I won't go into in this question.

For a sanity check, I ran `longerr.exe 1000 2>test.txt` in `cmd.exe`; it inserted no spurious linebreaks.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838633/why-does-powershell-chops-message-on-stderr

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler: Thank you! That resolved the problem I mentioned at the end of my question, and required switching to a programming pattern which obviates the main problem of my question. I posted an answer detailing things. It's a really ugly solution if one wants to avoid shelling out to `cmd.exe`, but at least it's an explanation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to [TessellatingHeckler's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48655624/powershell-stderr-redirect-to-file-inserts-newlines#comment84311527_48655624) pointing me to the question [Why does PowerShell chops message on stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33838633/why-does-powershell-chops-message-on-stderr), I've been able to fix both problems in my question—the main one and the one I mentioned at the end. The key is the following:

> The complete output on `stderr` of the executable is simply split across several objects of type `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`. The actual splitting seems to be non deterministic **(*)**. Moreover, the partial strings are stored inside the property `Exception` instead of `TargetObject`. Only the first `ErrorRecord` has a non-null `TargetObject`.
>
> ⋮
>
> (*) It depends on the order of write/flush calls of the program in relation to the read calls of the Powershell. If one adds a fflush(stderr) after each fprintf() in my test program below, there will be much more ErrorRecord objects. Except the first one, which seems deterministic, some of them include 2 output lines and some of them 3.

With this, I was able to modify `longerr.exe` to also reproduce the bug I alluded to at the end:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (args.Length == 1)
        {
            System.Console.Error.WriteLine(new string('x', int.Parse(args[0])));
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < int.Parse(args[1]); i++)
            {
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine("\n");
                System.Console.Error.WriteLine(new string('x', int.Parse(args[0])));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the PowerShell script which works (and efficiently):

```
$p_out = 'success.txt'
$p_err = 'error.txt'

try
{
    [Environment]::CurrentDirectory = $PWD
    $append = $false
    $out = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($p_out, $append)
    $err = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($p_err, $append)

    .\longerr.exe 2000 4 2>&1 |
        % {
            if ($_ -is [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]) {
                # https://stackoverflow.com/a/33858097/2328341
                if ($_.TargetObject -ne $null) {
                    $err.WriteLine(); 
                }
                $err.Write($_.Exception.Message)
            } else {
                $out.WriteLine($_)
            }
        }
}
finally
{
    $out.Close()
    $err.Close()
}
```

Notes:

1. Without the test for `TargetObject`, I would eliminate the main problem I was focusing on in my question, but I would still get the "bug" I mentioned at the end, which the linked SO question addresses.
2. I could have used `Out-File` (with `-NoNewline`) instead of `StreamWriter`, but there are two problems with that:

   1. Windows Defender was making all the file opens and closes over an order of magnitude slower than when I turned off "Real-time protection" (either globally or on the directory containing `error.txt` and `success.txt`).
   2. Even without Defender slowing things down, `StreamWriter` out-performs `Out-File` by over an order of magnitude. For reference, I'm using a [Samsung 960 EVO](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820147594) for storage.
3. The [`StreamWriter(string, bool)` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_String_System_Boolean_) writes UTF-8 with no Byte-Order Mark (BOM), while PowerShell 5.1's redirection operators `>` and `>>` [use UTF-16 LE with BOM](https://mohitgoyal.co/2017/03/03/understanding-default-encoding-and-change-the-same-in-powershell/). For reference, PowerShell 6.0 defaults [to UTF-8 with no BOM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6#default-encoding-is-utf-8-without-a-bom).

(I've included stdout for completeness in real-world situations.) Now, that's an *absolutely ridiculous amount of work* to get the following functionality of `cmd.exe`:

```
$ .\longerr.exe 2000 4 2>error.txt
```